# How to avoid Tabs on footer when redirecting to next page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, navigation, ionic3

i have a Tabs layout here is my [image: first] page. On click on any of the item i am navgating to next 'this.navCtrl.push(NextPage);`.

But the problem is on my second page also i am getting the tabs take a look at this [image]. after navigation done i no longer need the tabs in my second page.

> how to avoid the tabs footer in the second page.

Comment: Which version of Ionic2 are you using?

Comment: `Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Node Version: v6.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Ionic 2.0.0-rc.1, you can set to hide the tabs when entering a child page in the app's config object by using the config property `tabsHideOnSubPages`. You can find more information [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/).

> **tabsHideOnSubPages** (boolean): Whether to hide the tabs on child pages
>   or not. If true it will not show the tabs on child pages.

You need to include the config object in the `NgModule`, inside the `IonicModule.forRoot(...)` method like this:

```
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ MyApp ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      // Configs for your app
      tabsHideOnSubPages: true
      // ...
    }, {}
  )],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ MyApp ],
  providers: []
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to toggle tab bar visibility with css as tabs is actually a component containing nested views.

So you'd better detect selected page and toggle `tabbar` display. You can track selected page by `selectedIndex` or add class depending on it.